# How to speed up the populating of listview in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, performance, listview

This is the code for populating the listview

```
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                itemcoll(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
            Next
            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcoll)
            myLVstyle.Items.Add(lvi)
        Next
```

I tried using the following:

```
myLVstyle.SuspendLayout()

        my code for populating listview

myLVstyle.ResumeLayout()
```

and

```
myLVstyle.BeginUpdate()

        my code for populating listview

myLVstyle.EndUpdate()
```

I'm using mysql for database and this is my select statement:

```
SELECT STYLE_CODE, `DESC`, FAB_CONS, DATE_CREAT, LAST_ORD, QTY_ORD, GRAPHIC, NOTES1, NOTES2, NOTES3 FROM style
```

But non of these help me speed up the populating of listview.
Thank you.

Comment: for next is sooo ugly, can't you for each true them?

Comment: HI @Lectere, what is the difference of the two?

Comment: You automaticly have a reference to the current object, you will get less errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the:

```
BeginUpdate
```

and the

```
EndUpdate
```

If thats not speeding up things, you should look for a faster SQL server.

One little test you could try, is fill the listview with the same number of random items, and skip getting it from SQL. This way you can pinpoint if SQL is the bottleneck...

So you get something like;

```
with myLVstyle
    .beginupdate()
    for each row as [rowtype] in ds.tables.rows
        for each col as [coltype] in row.colums
            dim NewLvi as listviewitem = .items.add(col.itemcoll)
        next
    next
    .endupdate()
end with
```

Comment: Ahh ok sir, I will try this one